# Number of words in a string that are not in an array of strings

Tags: java

I want to create a method that returns the number of words in a string that have no occurrences of words in the array of strings. I want to implement this logic only using anything in the java.lang package.

```
public int count(String a, String[] b) {

}
```

E.g.

```
count("  hey   are  you there    ", new String[]{ "are", "i", "am"})
```

would return 3 as there is the word "are" in the string.

First off, I think I have to use the string.split function to convert the string to an array of strings. Any ideas?

Comment: Why `3`? `"are"` is only in the `String` once. What if the array had `hey` in it too?

Comment: "*number of words in a string that have no occurrences of words in the array of strings*" - That's confusing.

Comment: So there are 4 words in the string but since there is a word "are" that is in the array of strings that appears in the string, it should deduct the number count by 1 hence should return 3.

Comment: Yeah. I tried splitting the string to convert into an array of strings.

Comment: So like, String[] splitted = a.trim().split("\\s+");
Will this work to convert the string to an array of strings?

Comment: Do you need count only unique words, or you need any word occurrence? For example if `you` will be twice in source string, will you count it twice?

Comment: @KenBekov Hmm, so lets say the string has "   are are are are " and the array of Strings contains {"are"}, then it will return 0. So yeah it will count.

Comment: @J.Young, I think he was asking about something like the string is `"hey hey are you there"` and the array is `{"are", "you", "there"}`. Should the answer be 1 or 2? I assume 2 simply because your problem statement doesn't say “distinct words”, but this still better be clarified.

Comment: Yes it will count as 2 but yeah this problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow the steps to complete the task.**

- Use `StringTokenizer` to tokenize the String `a`.
- Convert String Array `b` to `Collection`, so that you can check if it contains the given token.
- Use loop to get next `token` from `StringTokenizer` and check if it contains in `List`.

-

**Try below code, it'll work.**

**EDIT : Using `java.util` package.**

```
public int count(String a, String[] b) {
    java.util.StringTokenizer tokenizer = new java.util.StringTokenizer(a);
    java.util.List bList = java.util.Arrays.asList(b);
    int tokens = tokenizer.countTokens();
    int counter = tokens;
    for(int i=0;i<tokens;i++) {
        String token = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        if(bList.contains(token)) {
            counter--;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

By using this, you can get the counter in just one for loop.

**EDIT :: Using `java.lang` package only.**

```
public int count(String a, String[] b) {
    String[] words = a.split(" ");
    int tokens = words.length;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<tokens;i++) {
        String token = words[i].trim();
        if(token.length() <= 0) {
            continue;
        }
        wordCount++;
        for(String bItem : b) {
            if(bItem.equals(token)) {
                counter++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return wordCount - counter;
}
```

Comment: This method works and I will look into the StringTokenizer and List. But is the java.util.StringTokenizer, List, Arrays under java.lang? Because I want to implement this logic only using anything in java.lang. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, these are under `java.util` package..If you want to use `java.lang` package only, then you have to change the logic.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate then. I want to implement this using java.lang package only. But your method works super good though!

Comment: Nice it works perfectly :) easy to understand logic too.

Comment: The first implementation doesn't make any sense. If you're going to use java.util anyway, better use a Set than a List. StringTokenizer doesn't make any sense too as it's mostly obsolete and much bulkier than just `split`. The second solution looks pretty nice, though. I just would've used `token.isEmpty()` instead of `token.length() <= 0` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do something like:

```
public int count(String a, String[] b) {
    int count = b.length;
    for(String s : b) if(a.contains(s)) count--;
    return count;
}
```

**EDIT:** I might have been confused, I thought you wanted the # of strings in `b` not in `a` (in your example it would still be 3). In that case, from your example, `split` seems inconvenient unless you use `regex`, so you could create a `String[]` using `Scanner`:

```
public int count(String a, String[] b) {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(a);
    while(scan.hasNext()) words.add(scan.next());

    int count = words.size();
    for(String s : words) if(/*b contains s*/) count--;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't spoonfeed. This answer doesn't even explain why it works. Although it mau be right, the asker may feel it's alright to create "code request" questions.

Comment: Bad idea. `a` may contain multiple instances of `s`. `a` may contain words that have `s` as a substring.

Comment: He wanted the amount of words of a which are not in b.

Comment: I get his logic but my mistake, I should have said that I would want to implement this without the use of importing any libraries in java.

Comment: Split *always* uses regexps, so “unless you use regex” makes no sense. Neither does that weird cast `(String[]) words.toArray()`.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov, by "unless you use regex", I meant doing a more complex `regex` than just `split(" ")`, which I know is still technically a `regex`, but you know what I meant. And `words.toArray()` returns `Object[]`, I assumed you had to cast it to `String[]` to use it in a `for-each` loop

Comment: You can do just `for (String s : words)`. Foreach accepts anything iterable, not just arrays. (Doesn't accept `Enumeration`, though.)

Comment: @SergeyTachenov, oh I didn't know, I thought it only accepted arrays, thanks for letting me know

Comment: @SergeyTachenov `split` actually uses a "fastpath" if the argument is 1 character long, avoiding the need to compile an expression to avoid overhead. Unless the implementation has changed, of course. I'm not at a computer, so I can't check, but I don't see any reason for them to change it.

Comment: @Vince, I didn't know about that, interesting! Still, I was talking about the API, not the implementation. Technically, the argument to `split` is a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You logic should go somewhat like this:

1. Split `a`, right. Now you have a list of words. In a real life, you should probably also try to clarify the requirement—what exactly is a “word”? A reasonable assumption is that it's a sequence of non-whitespace characters, but could be something different (for example, a sequence of letters).
2. Iterate over `a` and check whether each word is in `b`. If it isn't, increment your counter. But every check is a linear search in `b`, leading to the total complexity of O(nm), so...
3. Before iterating, convert `b` into a `HashSet`. This is a linear operation, but then your main loop will also become a linear operation, therefore the total complexity will be O(m + n).
4. If you have to do this thing repeatedly for different strings, but the same word list, consider creating a `WordCounter` class so you only have to create the `HashSet` once in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i would want a solution without the use of HashSet  and ArrayList or anything by that means. So without importing anything, if that makes sense.

Comment: @J.Young, no, that doesn't make any sense. You'll have to stop at (2) in that case though. So you'll have O(nm). If the word list was sorted, you could reduce it to O(n log m) by using binary search, but it isn't even sorted in your example.

Comment: @J.Young, not to mention that you already have to import `String`, even though it's implicitly, but it's still an import.

Comment: @J.Young, or, alternatively, you may wish to roll out your own hash set. It would probably be a real mess, though, but very educational.